# mpdf orientation not working in mozilla

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using **mPDF** library for converting php to **mPDF**.I have used following code for landscape orientation of A4 page.It works well on chrome but not on mozilla,unable to debug the problem. Please help me out.I am badly stuck here or suggest me another library which is compatible for both chrome and mozilla for converting **html**,**php**,**css** to pdf.Thanks in advance.

```
include('MPDF57/mpdf.php');



$text="<html><head></head><body><table width='100px' border='1' ><tr><td>sno</td><td>name</td></tr><tr><td style='width:10px;'>1</td><td>test1</td></tr></table></body></html>";

//code for landscape A4 orientation
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',42,15,57,57,20,17);
$mpdf->AddPage('L');
$mpdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($text);
$mpdf->AliasNbPages();
$mpdf->Output();
```